# Autocomplete in .net with mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, algorithm, autocomplete

I am using MongoDB via .Net.And I would like to make a autocomplete api.
But I do not know how to match in one case.
Let me explain it by giving example;

```
 I wrote -- Results
    "Ema" => "Email" , ""...
    "Emasil" => "Email", ""...
    "Emasil Li" => "Email List", ""...
    "Emasil Lit" => "Email List", ""...
    "Emasil Litk" => "Email List", ""...
```

as shown the above, even if I wrote it mistake, it gave me the results.This is what exactly I need.But I don't have any idea how to do this.
Can you please show me a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MongoDB can help you with that entirely (could be wrong).  Seems like you want to create a spelling corrector / predictive text type solution?  There are prebuilt libraries that can do that for you, like this one used by google written in Python: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html.  I guess you could store the dictionary or collection of potential text matches in mongodb and somehow incorporate that in your solution, but I'm not aware of a means of querying the fields of a collection in a spell check type manner.

Answer (score 0):

Answers the question [Implement autocomplete on MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223841/implement-autocomplete-on-mongodb) may be able to help you.

In general your problem is related to [fuzzy string search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching). The basic algorithm used the Levenshtein distance for determining how strings are similar each other. But there are another algorithms such as bitap algorithm, Needleman–Wunsch algorithm, Spell-checker method, N-gram method and others. You may find more details for example in the article [Fuzzy string search](http://ntz-develop.blogspot.ru/2011/03/fuzzy-string-search.html), or [Fuzzy search algorithm (approximate string matching algorithm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337135/fuzzy-search-algorithm-approximate-string-matching-algorithm). Also check the search libraries such as [Apache Lucene.Net](https://github.com/apache/lucenenet) (see [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) for more details), [fuzzystring](https://github.com/kdjones/fuzzystring).